# How to access a file belonging to some other group?

Tags: filesystem

I saw this problem in an online hacking competition. The question asked us to print the contents of the file "secret"

```
bruce@ip-10-144-4-86:/home/hacker-weekly$ ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x   2 hacker-weekly hacker-weekly  4096 Nov 12 19:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x 222 root          root          12288 Dec 27 06:27 ../
-r--r-----   1 root          secret          373 Nov 12 19:19 secret

bruce@ip-10-144-4-86:/home/hacker-weekly$ stat secret
  File: `secret'
  Size: 373             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 141569      Links: 1
Access: (0440/-r--r-----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1004/  secret)
Access: 2012-11-24 13:14:40.942961879 +0000
Modify: 2012-11-12 19:19:51.079654457 +0000
Change: 2012-11-12 19:19:51.079654344 +0000
 Birth: -

bruce@ip-10-144-4-86:/home/hacker-weekly$ getent group secret
secret:x:1004:guest

bruce@ip-10-144-4-86:/home/hacker-weekly$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l

bruce@ip-10-144-4-86:/home/hacker-weekly$ groups
bruce

bruce@ip-10-144-4-86:/home$ netstat -tulen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          7287
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          7289
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          6522
```

PS - I can gather other information also if you tell me what command to run on shell

Answer (score 4):

There is **no official way** to access a file if its permissions do not allow you to do so. Any such possibility would be a (severe) bug in the OS. So there's no magic command which reads such files or, say, a magic switch for some command:

```
cat --ignore-permissions /home/hacker-weekly/secret
```

That's why it is called a competition - you need to work around the OS security machinery or find a mis-configuration of the machine which would allow you to access the file.

In this case, I think, the give-away is the `guest` user which is in the `secret` group - I think you need somehow to become `guest`.

If you had physical access to the machine, you could also reboot into a single-user mode or unplug the hard drive and put it into another machine.

Comment: I have been racking my brains on this problem for days. I can't take it anymore. I don't have physical access to the machine. If I do  su -c "cat secret" guest it asks for a password which I don't have.

Comment: @Bruce: That's the whole point of such competitions - you won't find a solution in a manual. It's like a brainteaser :) One (rather naive) option to try is to search for SUID/SGID scripts in the system which might give you access to the file...

Comment: Tried find / -xdev -type f -perm +g=s -print and find / -xdev -type f -perm +u=s -print. Got no files/scripts.